# Rotate UIImage or UIImageView custom degree

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, image-rotation

i want rotate a UIImage or a UIImageView, i have tried a lot of code, and search everywhere, but i can't find a valid solution, i'm explain the problem, i download a image from the web and then i resize it in this way:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
//UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
}
```

and the resize work very well, then
i have attached my UIImage at my UIImageView and then i have rotate my UIImageView in this way:

```
self.myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(-2));
```

but in this way the border are pixelled and there is aliasing, so i have tried to rotate first the UIImage and then give the image to my UIImageView, and i have find a lot of similar code, in particular i use this class Extension:

http://www.catamount.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=967

and in this way, the border are antialised but instead loss quality the image, it's more fuzzy, and it's not sharp like first of rotate it, anyone have a good solution?

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

for rotate image.. you can use this IBAction ... for each and every button click, the image will be rotate by 90 degree...

```
-(IBAction)rotateImageClick:(id)sender{

UIImage *image2=[[UIImage alloc]init];
image2 = [self imageRotatedByDegrees:self.roateImageView.image deg:(90)]; //Angle by 90 degree
self.roateImageView.image = image2;
imgData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2,0.9f);
```

}

for rotating image u only have to pass UIimage and rotating degrees for the following method

```
- (UIImage *)imageRotatedByDegrees:(UIImage*)oldImage deg:(CGFloat)degrees
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
#pragma mark - imageRotatedByDegrees Method

- (UIImage *)imageRotatedByDegrees:(UIImage*)oldImage deg:(CGFloat)degrees{

    // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,oldImage.size.width, oldImage.size.height)];

    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * M_PI / 180);
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t;

    CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;
    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
    CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

    //   // Rotate the image context
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, (degrees * M_PI / 180));

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-oldImage.size.width / 2, -oldImage.size.height / 2, oldImage.size.width, oldImage.size.height), [oldImage CGImage]);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

I think this link will be help.......! Rotate Original Image by clicking button in Objective C

http://adrianmobileapplication.blogspot.com/2015/03/rotate-original-image-by-clicking.html